# Optimization of in memory load time of image

Tags: image, imagemagick

I am using the `ImageMagick` utility to resize the images. But before that i download the image from S3 and keep it in memory just to reduce time. But still when i print the `time taken to get the image from s3` and `time to load the image in memory` it comes out to be `300-400 ms` and `500-900ms`. So my question is time to get the image from s3 will depands on from which region i download the image. But `time to load the image in memory` is taking `500-900ms`. So is there any way i can optimize it ?

```
           string accessKey = "ACCESS_KEY";
           string secretKey = "SECRET_KEY";

           AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
                        accessKey,
                        secretKey
                        );         

           GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
           {
               BucketName = "BUCKEY_NAME",
               Key = KeyName
           };

           Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
           sw.Start();
           var response = client.GetObject(request);
           sw.Stop();        
           Console.WriteLine("Time to get the image : " + sw.Elapsed.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);

           sw.Reset();
           sw.Start();
           MagickImage imgStream = new MagickImage(response.ResponseStream);
           sw.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine("Time to load image in memory : " + sw.Elapsed.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
```

Comment: If you have lots of images to download and they have high latency like that, I would suggest you download them in parallel using `GNU Parallel` and that will make a massive difference - since all the 500ms delays will pass in parallel. If it is just one image, sorry I have no ideas.

Comment: there would be millions of images..... which will be downloaded....Also, utility which you told is for linux....but i am using .net C# along with imagemagick. So any other alternative for the .net

Comment: Mmmm... it's kind of hard to do a serious job with a toy operating system ;-( I can only suggest you consider starting 32-64 threads each one grabbing a file in parallel then you will incur the delays all in parallel instead of sequentially one after the other.

Comment: Are you using the Q8 version of Magick.NET? Using that will half the amount of memory that is being used and that will also increase the performance.